# Calcular la diferencia entre dos parámetros de tipo Date

Tags: java, android-studio, datetime

Estoy intentado de realizar un calculo para que me muestre cuanto tiempo lleva el usuario utilizando un servicio. En este momento mantengo la hora de inicio y la hora actual como variables de tipo date.

```
Date horaIngreso = Mon Dec 16 00:10:20 GMT-03:00 2019;
Date horaActual = Mon Dec 16 00:55:05 GMT-03:00 2019;
```

he intentado pasar las fechas a long, para luego restarlas entre ellas:

```
long total = (horaactual.getTime()-horaIngreso.getTime());
```

y luego este pasarlo a String para obtener solamente la hora y mostrarla:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateHours = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    tot = dateHours.format(total);
```

Pero obtengo resultados errados todo el tiempo, con la acción anterior obtengo

tot = '1969-12-31' **21:50:16**

Agradeceria su ayuda.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega esto a tu código, con la variable **horas** sabrás cuántas horas han utilizado el servicio.

```
long horas = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(total, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Si prefieres en minutos usa esto:

```
long minutos = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(total, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla para resolver tu problema es convirtiendo el resultado de la diferencia:

```
int diferenciaDeTiempo = (int)( (horaActual.getTime().getTime() - horaIngreso.getTime().getTime()) / (1000 * 60));
```

El (1000*60) es para pasarlo a minutos si lo quieres en horas solo tienes que multiplicar *60.

Saludos,